# How to get the CodeName of a sheet

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm trying to use xlwings to deal with Excel files similarlly to what I used to do via VBA.
As I've learned so far, I can access a spreadsheet using name or index. but both of which can be modified. Is there a way to access a sheet using the codename?
Here is an example:
I have a workbook with 3 sheets inside. one of it is a special sheet that I've modified its CodeName in VBA editor to shReport. So no matter who uses this file and rename the sheet to "Report" or "NiceReport", in VBA I can always use shReport.cells(1,1) to get what I need.
But in xlwings, I can only (seems to be) use sht = wb.Sheets['Report'] or sht = wb.Sheets[0] to get the sheet as object. this will fail if user rename the sheet or inseart or delete sheets which will change the index.
So I wonder if it's possible to use the CodeName to refer to the sheet. I've tried in api and don't get any return of CodeName. the code below will return nothing

```
for sht in wk.Sheets:  
    print(sht.api.CodeName)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Lemon please see upon my updates to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code does not work, however this complete code example works

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('Book1.xlsx')

for sheet in wb.sheets:
    print("Sheet Name: " + str(sheet))
    print("Code Name: " + str(wb.sheets(sheet).api.CodeName))
```

The last line can be split into

```
sht = wb.sheets(sheet)
print("Code Name: " + str(sht.api.CodeName))
```

so its the same as your line of code.

From what I can see you would only get the Code Name from a selected sheet so have to check each sheet for the one that matches as you did.